# How to use printf with Arduino's serial ports without an intermediary buffer?

Tags: avr, printf

How to use `printf` with Arduino's streams without an intermediary buffer? The following seems unnecessary:

```
char buf[256];
sprintf(buf, ...);
Serial.print(buf);
```

Is there a way to connect `HardwareSerial` or `SoftwareSerial` to a libc stream or is there a custom implementation of `printf` that does this?

Answer (score 6):

Sure - here's a Hello, World program that uses printf(). Everything that mentions "uart" is what connects printf() to your output stream. `uart_putchar()` does the actual outputting to ... someplace. That's what you'd modify to direct the C standard output to a different device - SofwareSerial, for instance:

```
// Hello, World program using printf()

#include <Arduino.h>

static FILE uartout = { 0 };   // FILE struct
static int uart_putchar(char c, FILE *stream);


void setup() {
   // For printf: fills in the UART file descriptor with pointer to putchar func.
   fdev_setup_stream(&uartout, uart_putchar, NULL, _FDEV_SETUP_WRITE);
   stdout = &uartout;

   Serial.begin(9600);
   printf("Hello, World!\n");
}


void loop( void ){
   printf("Elapsed time: %ld\n", millis());
}


// uart_putchar - char output function for printf
static int uart_putchar (char c, FILE *stream)
{
   if( c == '\n' )
      Serial.write('\r');
   Serial.write(c) ;
   return 0 ;
}
```